# Can't open App Settings in Jetpack compose app while permission handling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I got a sample code for runtime permission handling where someone has done almost all the permission handling in the main activity (I ran and it works perfectly). I decided to move the code to another activity to reduce the complexity from the MainActivity. I solve a lot of problems while doing it but I am stuck in this place,

The problem is that I can't open the app setting function anymore, here's the code that was in the main activity,

```
            onDismiss = viewModel::dismissDialog,
            onOkClick = {
                viewModel.dismissDialog()
                multiplePermissionResultLauncher.launch(
                    arrayOf(permission)
                )
            },
            onGoToAppSettingsClick = ::openAppSettings // Here raises error
        )
    }
}

fun Activity.openAppSettings() {
    Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
    ).also(::startActivity)
}
```

The Activity.openAppSettings() is not causing any error, the way of calling the function is causing an error I think (But it works fine when It was in the main activity).

Please give a suggestion how can I do it correctly.

Comment: `// Here raises error` -- what exactly is the error?

Comment: the compiler declares an unresolved reference "openAppSettings" -- the expectation is that the compiler should see the extension function for Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I find,

```
fun openAppSettings(activity: Activity) {
    val intent = Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        Uri.fromParts("package", activity.packageName, null)
    )
    activity.startActivity(intent)
}
```

The function should take an Activity type parameter.

Comment: this is a different style function.  we are still faced with the issue of passing in the reference to the activity that this compose function is running.

Answer (score 0):

you can use context instead of activity

```
val context = LocalContext.current
Button(onClick = {
            openAppSettings(context)
        }) {Text(text = "open Setting")}
```

and in the function:

```
fun openAppSettings(context: Context) {
    val intent = Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
        Uri.fromParts("package", context.packageName, null)
    )
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

if for any reason this is not working for you then try to cast activity from context..

```
val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
```

and pass activity to function of Intent launcher